# Multi-thread a Mongo find operation

Tags: multithreading, mongodb

I have a periodic cron job that fetches all new documents from a collection from mongodb after its previous execution and process on it. Now document count grown too large that a single script cannot handle.
So I have to go with multi thread. But the issue is, multiple threads cannot fetch and process single document.

**So what are the best practices to split a single find operation to multiple thread.**

Note: Thread can be on separate machines and collection size will be varying day by day

Comment: A cheap solution is run the same script, but, for example, 5x as often. Less new docs on each invocation.

Comment: These process are time consuming and chances of lag if process didn't complete before next executions

Answer (score 0):

[Change Streams](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) (available on Mongo 3.6 and above) allows you to tail data changes & run whatever script you'd like when there are updates. This allows fully realtime updates.

[mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) allows fast dumping of data in a collection based on a query.

If your script can't keep up, best practice is to put documents on to a queue, and have workers take documents off of the queue.